# why do i keep getting <function __main__.Boat.boat(max_speed)> as an output

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self,max_speed,speed_unit):
        self.max_speed = max_speed
        self.speed_unit = speed_unit
    def car(self):
        print('Car with the maximum speed of ',self.max_speed,' ',self.speed_unit)


class Boat:
    def __init__(self,max_speed):
        self.max_speed = max_speed
    def boat(max_speed):
        print('Boat with the maximum speed of ',self.max_speed,'knots')
```

Comment: Your code *doesn't output anything*.

Comment: is this all of the code? because i cant see any output stuff here like you doesnt even call car and boat function.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Note that we cannot help you with a minimal, reproducible example. The code as shown only defines the classes, it does not run or print anything. Please [edit] your question to include the *minimum* amount of needed to reproduce your problem. See the [ask] page for details.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, [mre] specifically

Comment: Judging by the title, do you by any chance run code such as ``print(my_boat.boat)``? It would appear you merely looking up the method, not calling it. If my assumption is correct, you need code such as ``my_boat.boat()`` (note the extra parentheses to make a call, and the removal of an outer ``print``) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you are trying to do.
Be sure to add parentheses `()` when you call a function.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self,max_speed,speed_unit):
        self.max_speed = max_speed
        self.speed_unit = speed_unit
    def car(self):
        print(f"Car with the maximum speed of {self.max_speed} {self.speed_unit}")


class Boat:
    def __init__(self,max_speed):
        self.max_speed = max_speed
    def boat(self):
        print(f'Boat with the maximum speed of {self.max_speed} knots')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    car = Car(15, "km")
    car.car()

    boat = Boat(20)
    boat.boat()
```